# TypeError: handlebars is not a function error

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am a newbie of node.js, i use template engine express-handlebar but i get problem is: **TypeError: handlebars is not a function at Object. ** . I have search lot but not any answer to fix. my code is below:

`````
const morgan = require('morgan');
const handlebars  = require('express-handlebars');
const app=express();
const port =3000;

// hTTP logger
app.use(morgan('combined'));

//templace engie
app.engine('handlebars',handlebars());
app.set('view engine','handlebars');
app.get('/',(req,res)=> {   
    return res.send('hello world');    
});
app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));````
`````

Comment: What version of `express-handlebars` do you use?

Comment: it is version 6.0.2

Comment: `app.engine('handlebars',handlebars());` needs to be `app.engine('handlebars',handlebars.engine());`

Answer (score 0):

For version 6.0.2, the `express-handlebars` package exports `create`, `engine` function. See [source code](https://github.com/express-handlebars/express-handlebars/blob/v6.0.2/lib/index.ts) The basic usage should be:

```js
const { engine } = require("express-handlebars");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

//templace engie
app.engine("handlebars", engine());
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.send("hello world");
});
app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);
```